# Use public function in sql string

Tags: vb.net

I have a project in vb.net that uses a mysql backend. In my project I have a module that contains a number of public functions that I call from different forms. Now I am trying to get data from my db to populate a grid but one of the columns needs to be calculated using one of my public functions. How do I call the function from my SQL string to get the data for that particular column in the grid. I'm getting the data from the db into a datatable and binding it to my grid.

--Edit---

This is the code of the function my want to call from my select query:

```
Public Function getCurrentQuantity(ByRef ItemID As Integer) As Double
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(gen.connString)
    Dim result As Double
    Dim recValue As Double 'quantity received
    Dim issValue As Double 'quantity issued
    Dim adjValueNeg As Double 'negative adjustment of quantity on hand
    Dim adjValuePos As Double 'positive adjustment of quantity on hand
    Dim p_retValue As Double 'quantity returned to suppliers
    Dim i_retValue As Double 'quantity returned to stores
    Dim openValue As Double ' opening qty
    Dim countLast As Integer = doCount("ID", "inventory_current", " WHERE Item = " & ItemID)
    Dim stockDate As Date 'stock date is used to determine where to pick the opening balance from
    Dim hasLastStockBal As Boolean 'to determine if the item has a last stock balance
    Dim tranTypes As New List(Of String) 'creating a list of the different transaction types to loop through them
    tranTypes.AddRange({"RECV", "ISSU", "ADJN", "ADJP", "RETN", "RETI", "OBAL"})
    Try
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        If countLast = 0 Then 'no last inventory so opening bal will be from the item table
            hasLastStockBal = False
        Else
            hasLastStockBal = True
        End If
        For i = 0 To 6 'loop through the list of transaction types
            sql = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM stock_dairy WHERE EntryDate > @StockDate AND Item = @Item AND EntryType = @Type"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockDate", stockDate)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", ItemID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", tranTypes(i))
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "dat")
            rowscount = ds.Tables("dat").Rows.Count
            If rowscount = 0 Then
                result = 0
            Else
                If IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dat").Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
                    result = 0
                Else
                    result = ds.Tables("dat").Rows(0).Item(0)
                End If
            End If
            If i = 0 Then 'assign the retrieved variable based on the For..Next position
                recValue = result
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                issValue = result
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                adjValueNeg = result
            ElseIf i = 3 Then
                adjValuePos = result
            ElseIf i = 4 Then
                p_retValue = result
            ElseIf i = 5 Then
                i_retValue = result
            ElseIf i = 6 Then
                If hasLastStockBal = True Then
                    openValue = dLookup("Quantity", "inventory_current", " WHERE Item = " & ItemID)
                Else
                    openValue = result
                End If
            End If
        Next
        result = openValue + (((recValue - p_retValue) + adjValuePos) - ((issValue - i_retValue) + adjValueNeg)) 'sum up and return
        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbExclamation, "Unexpected Error")
        Return 0
    Finally
        ds.Reset()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If your function is simple you can create a calculated column in your table. But your question lacks many details. An example of your code with the function and the logic to use when you call the db would be useful

Comment: So my sql string is a simple select query that retrieves a list of items from my database. The function uses ItemID as a parameter to calculate the current inventory of an item. The function is not simple as it considers many variables including calculation method the user wants, opening stock, purchases, consumption etc. so i don’t know if it can be calculated column in my table. But basically I want to retrieve the Items along with their current inventory (calculated) and display in the grid

Comment: Gee, if only there was some way that we could see the actual code of this function. Hey, I know!  You could actually post the code and then we wouldn't have to guess. I can't believe no one has thought of that before.

Comment: Instead of "calling your function from sql" do: 1. Load data from database, 2. Use your function to calculated values with your function. 3. Add calculated results to data for displaying.

Comment: Thanks All, what Fabio is proposing is what I ended up doing but I’m worried about speed. With about 100 rows it takes almost almost .57 secs. This table in production will hold anything between 2000 and 4000 rows so it could take over 10 secs to display. Posting my code shortly

Comment: if you have access to the DB you may want to try using LinqToSQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/ makes the query more transparent and might be better in performance too...

Comment: Maybe if you don't loop your queries but sort the results later by transactionType should give better performance...?

Comment: Thanks. I split the function into bits and I’m not sure why but it runs faster. Thanks all.